# VBA Editor Icons Vanish when hover over them

Tags: excel, vba, icons

When I hover over the Toolbaricons in Excel VBA Editor, they are vanishing (See Pic).

[image: Pic where Icons are vanished]

Any idea how to fix this?

I tried:

- Closing and Opening the VBA Editor, Excel
- Open an empty workbook,
- Restart the PC

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue.

Apparently this was caused by Windows Update KB4034664

Just found out there is a fix.
The problem is listed as a Windows problem on dual monitor setup's where the main monitor is not top left (my setup).
The patch is KB4039884.

REF: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=2044983